# A "to[out=x,in=y]" curve and a "plot(\x,{cos(\x)})" in tikz in the same draw command

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I am trying to draw a curve followed by a plot in the same draw command. However, this doesn't work even though a line does. The following code helps understand the issue:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} %This works!
\draw[domain=-1:1] plot(\x,{cos(\x*100)}) to[out=-60,in=180] (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture} %This does too!
 \draw[domain=-1:1] (-2,-2) -- plot(\x,{cos(\x*100)}) to[out=-60,in=180] (2,2); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture} %This gives errors :( Why?
 \draw[domain=-1:1] (-2,-2) to[out=40,in=30] plot(\x,{cos(\x*100)}) to[out=-60,in=180] (2,2); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Could someone explain why this does not work and how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `to` operation is very different from `--`.
From the manual section 14.13 you can see that `to` installs, by default, a path of the form:

```
--(\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
```

For curved lines the pattern is similar and still uses the macros `\tikztotarget`, `\tikztosource` and `\tikztotarget`, which are setup by the code parsing the to operation. From the manual:

> The to operation is always followed by a ⟨coordinate⟩

This is so that `\tikztotarget` can be appropriately setup.

From section 22.2 one learns that `--plot` is a specific variant of `plot` which is defined explicitly. Since there is not special `to plot` operation, the `to` operation simply cannot understand a direct `plot` after itself.

The solution is then to manually compute the initial point of the plot with for example `\pgfmath` and put the target coordinate explicitly after the `to` operation, before the `plot`:

```
\def\startPlotX{-1}
\draw[domain=\startPlotX:1]
    (-2,-2)
    to[out=40,in=30] (\startPlotX,{cos(\startPlotX*100)})
    plot(\x,{cos(\x*100)})
    to[out=-60,in=180] (2,2);
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting. But why does it work then in the case of `(-2,-2) -- plot`? I thought the `(-2,-2)` gives the starting point and the begining of the domain used for `\x` gives the end point, from which the `plot` begins. What I don't understand is, why does it not work for `to` when it works for `--`.

Comment: Sorry, rushed answer, hopefully better now.

Comment: @learning2code One possibility for calculating the initial point: `\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=cos(\x*100);}]
 \draw[domain=-1:1] (-2,-2) to[out=40,in=30] (-1,{f(-1)}) plot(\x,{f(\x)}) to[out=-60,in=180] (2,2); 
\end{tikzpicture}` (Or use `cos(100*\x)` directly, instead of defining `f(\x)`.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. and @Bordaigorl Thank you!  `(-2,-2)to[out=40,in=30] (-1,{cos(-1*100)})plot` also works!